Next js generate static params breaks intercepting routes
Does anyone else encounter the same issue with intercepting routes, (modal), and `generate static params`? everything works fine when running `npm run dev`, but after building and running `npm run start`, the modal doesn't work, and instead of displaying the modal, it returns the route itself. The same problem with more details happened with someone else but didn't solved issue link is here: [Next.js Issue].
I deployed it on vercel and it didn't work .
When I remove the generate static params the modal works fine but I can't remove this as it is important for data fetching ( I use dynamic routes to get product by id )
